# Warnings Persist in docker compose up Despite Configured Environment Variables

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm currently learning Docker, and I've set up a PostgreSQL service using Docker Compose. Although I can access my database without issues, I'm puzzled by persistent warning messages during `docker compose up`. I have set environment variables in my .env file and referenced them in my docker-compose.yml file, yet I'm still seeing warning messages during `docker compose up`. The strange thing is that when I run `docker compose config`, it correctly shows the environment variables.

.env File:

```
DB_POSTGRES_FULL_URL=postgresql://${DB_POSTGRES_USER}:${DB_POSTGRES_PASSWORD}@${DB_POSTGRES_URL}:5434/${DB_POSTGRES_DB_NAME}?schema=public
DB_POSTGRES_URL=******
DB_POSTGRES_USER=******
DB_POSTGRES_PASSWORD=******
DB_POSTGRES_DB_NAME=******
JWT_SECRET_KEY=******
```

my docker-compose.yml:

```yaml
version: '3.8'
services:
  dev-db:
    restart: always
    image: postgres:15
    ports:
      - 5434:5432
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: "${DB_POSTGRES_USER}"
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: "${DB_POSTGRES_PASSWORD}"
      POSTGRES_DB: "${DB_POSTGRES_DB_NAME}"
    networks:
      - api
    volumes:
      - postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    mem_limit: 1gb
    cpus: 0.5
    command: ["postgres", "-c", "log_statement=all"]
networks:
  api:

volumes:
  postgres-data:
```

pnpm Scripts:

```json
    "db:dev:up": "docker compose --env-file .env up -d dev-db",
    "db:dev:rm": "docker compose rm dev-db -s -f -v",
    "db:dev:deploy": "pnpm db:dev:rm && pnpm db:dev:up && timeout 2 && pnpm prisma:dev:deploy",
```

When I run `docker compose config`, the output correctly shows the environment variables being set. However, when I use `docker compose up`, I still get warnings like:

```sql
    time="2023-12-06T19:54:11+01:00" level=warning msg="The \"DB_POSTGRES_USER\" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string."      
time="2023-12-06T19:54:11+01:00" level=warning msg="The \"DB_POSTGRES_PASSWORD\" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string."  
time="2023-12-06T19:54:11+01:00" level=warning msg="The \"DB_POSTGRES_URL\" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string."       
time="2023-12-06T19:54:11+01:00" level=warning msg="The \"DB_POSTGRES_DB_NAME\" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string."   
time="2023-12-06T19:54:11+01:00" level=warning msg="The \"DB_POSTGRES_USER\" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string."      
time="2023-12-06T19:54:11+01:00" level=warning msg="The \"DB_POSTGRES_PASSWORD\" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string."  
time="2023-12-06T19:54:11+01:00" level=warning msg="The \"DB_POSTGRES_URL\" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string."       
time="2023-12-06T19:54:11+01:00" level=warning msg="The \"DB_POSTGRES_DB_NAME\" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string."
```

I have verified that the environment variables are indeed set in my .env file and are correctly referenced in my docker-compose.yml. What could be causing these warnings, and how can I resolve this issue?

**Edit:**

When I include only the variables explicitly used in the PostgreSQL Docker image, the warnings disappear. It appears that including unused variables in the .env file triggers these warnings. Notably, the .env file is also used for the main application. Is there a specific reason for this behavior, and how can I ensure a clean setup without the warnings while maintaining a comprehensive .env file for both the main application and the PostgreSQL service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These warnings are coming from trying to parse the first line of the `.env` file:

```
DB_POSTGRES_FULL_URL=postgresql://${DB_POSTGRES_USER}:${DB_POSTGRES_PASSWORD}@${DB_POSTGRES_URL}:5434/${DB_POSTGRES_DB_NAME}?schema=public
```

If you aren't using it, then delete it. Otherwise for best backwards compatibility, don't include variables in the value, expand them to only have the values.

If you don't care about backwards compatibility, you may be able to get it to work by making this the last line of the file, the error message implies it's trying to expand it, but I've never used that feature and I know that older versions of compose didn't support that.

Comment: I cannot rename them, these are default env vars used by the postgresql image

Edit: I tried your solution and I still got the warning

Comment: @VGontier-cmd I overlooked the first line of your `.env`, where is `DB_POSTGRES_FULL_URL=postgresql://${DB_POSTGRES_USER}:${DB_POSTGRES_PASSWORD}@${DB_POSTGRES_URL}:5434/${DB_POSTGRES_DB_NAME}?schema=public` used?

Comment: Yes, it's used in my main application, but as you said, the problem comes from using variables in the value. Thanks!

Comment: The solution for me was to declare the `DB_POSTGRES_FULL_URL` variable at the end of the .env file to get rid of those warnings cause the variables in the value need to be declared before being handled by the Postgres service. (declaration order doesn't seem to matter for `docker-compose` this is why it was working).